# User unable to connect to network shares

Tags: windows, active-directory

I have a user is no longer able to access all mapped network drives/shares. He was able to access them in the past.  Error message indicates drive not found.  Other network services are operable (internet, e-mail, etc.)  Other logins on the same computer are able to use network drives, but the user has the same permissions.

User is runing Windows XP, server is Windows 2003.  User is logging into a windows domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Discoverd that the 'account name' field of his user properties page on domain controller was blank. Re-entered and operation was restored.